# Get file path starting inside workspace folder - vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm trying to figure out how to get the relative file path starting from the workspace folder. So for example if the workspace folder is called My App and the file path is to the current folder is

`file:///c%3A/Users/Bob/Documents/My%20App/backend/connections/server.js`

Then I want to be able to store in a variable only `backend/connections/server.js` so it would exclude the workspace folder with the `%20` in it. Currently

`vscode.window.activeTextEditor.document.uri;`

outputs

`file:///c%3A/Users/Bob/Documents/My%20App/backend/connections/server.js`.

Is there a method I can call that I'm not using or an easy way to do this without having to do some regex expression?

Comment: use `vscode.Uri.path` or `vscode.Uri.fsPath`

Comment: When I try either of those, I get ```Property 'fsPath' does not exist on type 'typeof Uri'.ts``` or ```Property 'path' does not exist on type 'typeof Uri'.ts```

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#Uri

Answer (score 0):

The short answer: no

Visual Studio Code will does not pass any awareness of itself into the code it hosts. While you can [access the $workspaceFolder variable inside Code's launch.json and tasks.json](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference), your code itself doesn't have access to those variables.

And even if it could, as soon as you would move your code outside of your development environment, it would break, as that $workspaceFolder would no longer be there.

If you want to make provisions for doing special stuff while in a dev environment, you'll have to define what you consider the workspace folder to be - there is no way for you to get that dynamically.